# PyCharm não reconhece biblioteca instalada

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Alguem saberia me dizer o motivo do Pycharm não reconhecer o pandas?
Ele está na lista de interpretador, porem o `read_excel` não aparece na lista de funções. Lembrando que usei `import pandas` normal mesmo.

[image: interpreter]

[image: comando]

Comment: No momento em que escrevo a ultima versão do módulo pandas é a versão 1.4.1

Comment: Está na lista de interpretadores, mas já fez a instalação da dependência via o `pip`? Poderia instalar no venv do pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você, provavelmente, está utilizando um environment/interpreter diferente para a execução do seu código. Note que no primeiro print você está vendo as bibliotecas instaladas no environment **Python 3.9 (dataAnalyticsB2B)**.

Confira agora se o seu projeto está sendo **executado** com esse mesmo environment e, se for diferente, é só selecionar este que possui o Pandas instalado.